# Laravel response download does not download zip file and show no errros

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to download an existing zip file. response()->download as explained in [HTTP Responses - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses) does not start a download and show no errors.

Tried several combinations: with name, without name, with different headers, without headers, different folders and also with Response::download instead of response()->download.

In all of them the download doesn't start and I have no errors.

```php
$filename = 'test.zip';
$zip_file_path = storage_path("app/uploads/public/temp/{$filename}");
$headers = ["Content-Type" => "application/zip"];

return response()->download($zip_file_path, 'test.zip', $headers);
```

The file exists and if the path is not valid, I get the normal "file does not exist" error.

The extension=php_fileinfo.dll is uncommented.

Can you help me with more ideas?
I really wanted to use this function in order to use the deleteFileAfterSend(true) feature.

Thank you

Comment: So what's the output of `dd(response()->download($zip_file_path, 'test.zip', $headers))`?

Comment: Thank. I honestly did not remember to do that. I got this.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/17EewrrQ8s1uWekRO2-yKOJBEQpwIovWN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So that's your error :)
You can't just store this file from drive. You would have to use the drive API.

Comment: Well that makes sense. How can you understand that with the dump file?

Yet, I am not so sure how to do that..
To create the zip file I am using [Chumper/Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper)  

`$zipper = new Zipper;  
$result = $zipper->make($filename)->add($files)->close();`

Comment: Where $files are the files to be zipped. How can I do the same and store using the drive API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using ajax to call this function.
Ajax calls cannot return streams!

So the solution was, after this ajax call, redirect to a new controller's method that returns the response()->download :)